# how to add multiple javascript variable in html a href tag

Tags: javascript, html

I write this javascript but it's showing error. can anyone solve this how to write it correctly?

**actually I want to show button and on the button, I want link**

```
pop_str = pop_str + '<a href="'+ brand1 + 'vs' + brand2 + '/'><button class="btn master_btn">Compare Now!<button></a>';
```

Comment: what is the error and what you want to achieve?

Comment: i think this answer would help you !!! https://stackoverflow.com/a/6631748/10967697

Comment: Please note it is invalid to have interactive content (e.g. a `button`) inside a link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a . You are better off styling the link to something that resembles a button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `quote` on  `'/'` => `'/`

```
pop_str = pop_str + '<a href="'+ brand1 + 'vs' + brand2 + '"/><button class="btn master_btn">Compare Now!<button></a>';
```

Comment: actually it shows whole <button></button> tag in link?

Comment: yes  of course .They will parse the string and variable

Comment: not but that's not a solution that I want! on the button I want the link

Comment: for your question `I write this javascript but it's showing error. can anyone solve this how to write it correctly?` its not showing any other scenario .please update the correct question

Answer (score 2):

To simplify this you could use the back tick character `` ` ``:

```
pop_str =  `${pop_str}<a href="${brand1}vs${brand2}"><button class="btn master_btn">Compare Now!<button></a>`
```

You simply place your variables within `${variable}`

Comment: Right after a posted this someone showed a similar answer lol. But they're correct, using the back tick can be more efficient in this situation.

Comment: no, when I click on button then there is no link in your solution!